# React Native: Could not find method isNewArchitectureEnabled() for arguments on project :app

Tags: react-native

Trying to run React native project on my new device Macbook Pro got following error.[image]

My Device specification:[image]

Note: The project was running properly in my previous intel chip device.

Got stuck with an error and could not found the proper solution, any help and suggestion will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to provide the error messages and any other relevant information as text instead of images

Comment: In any case, I suggest you report this as a bug ~ https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

If the project use React native version < **0.68.0**, you consider first migrate the whole project to the newer like **>= 0.68**.

Run the following command to start the process of upgrading to the latest version:

```
npx react-native upgrade
```

You may specify a React Native version by passing an argument, e.g. to upgrade to **0.XX.X**

documentation here [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading)

---

if you have a react native version **>= 0.68.0** go to the

```
app/build.gradle
```

and you need to change many things like:

old version

```
...
/*** Architectures to build native code for in debug.
*/
def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")
```

new version

```
/*** Architectures to build native code for in debug.
*/
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}


...
defaultConfig {
...
buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        // We configure the CMake build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "-DNODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
        if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
            ndk {
                abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
    def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
        dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
        from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
        into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
    }
    def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
        dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
        from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
        into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        // If you wish to add a custom TurboModule or component locally,
        // you should uncomment this line.
        // preBuild.dependsOn("generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema")
        preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
        preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)

        // Due to a bug inside AGP, we have to explicitly set a dependency
        // between configureCMakeDebug* tasks and the preBuild tasks.
        // This can be removed once this is solved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207403732
        configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
        configureCMakeDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
        reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
            tasks.findByName("configureCMakeDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
            }
            tasks.findByName("configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
            }
        }
    }
}

splits {
  abi {
  ...
  include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
  }
}

dependencies {
...
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
// If new architecture is enabled, we let you build RN from source
// Otherwise we fallback to a prebuilt .aar bundled in the NPM package.
// This will be applied to all the imported transtitive dependency.
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
                .using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
                .because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
        substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine"))
                .using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
                .because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
    }
  }
}
...
def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
// To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
// - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
// - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
// - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true" }
```

I hope this help you, for more information you can check the upgrade helper tool [link](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/)

cheers ヽ( •_)ᕗ